# Assigning function output to variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#include <Assert.h>
#include <sstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

using namespace std;

// Prints the MAC address stored in a 6 byte array to stdout
static void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[])
{

    printf("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);

}

// Fetches the MAC address and prints it
static void GetMACaddress(void)
{
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[16];            // Allocate information for up to 16 NICs
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);       // Save the memory size of buffer

    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(           // Call GetAdapterInfo
        AdapterInfo,                            // [out] buffer to receive data
        &dwBufLen);                             // [in] size of receive data buffer
    assert(dwStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);          // Verify return value is valid, no buffer overflow

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;// Contains pointer to current adapter info
    do {
        PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address); // Print MAC address
        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;      // Progress through linked list
    }
    while(pAdapterInfo);                        // Terminate if last adapter
}

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    char mac[100];

        GetMACaddress(); // output is 00-19-D7-53-2D-14

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << "Text" << std::endl;
    cout << buffer.str();
        return 0;
    }
```

My question is how do I assign function `GetMACaddress();` output to variable. This: `mac = GetMACaddress(); // output is 00-19-D7-53-2D-14` don't worked. Help me please. Thank you.

The data type for returning MAC address is `unsigned char`.

Comment: Use `std::string` for that.

Comment: What's the return type of `GetMACaddress()`?

Comment: @Angew : `unsigned char` is the data type

Comment: What is output `00-19-D7-53-2D-14` coming from?

Comment: `unsinged char`, or `unsigned char*`?

Comment: `unsinged char` juanchopanza

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean by output: Do you mean that `00-19-D7-53-2D-14` is the "output" printed to the console, and you want to assign _that_ to a variable? That's different from the return value of the function.

Comment: Where does `GetMACaddress()` come from?

Comment: @ap yes you are correct. `00-19-D7-53-2D-14` is the output and I want assign this to variable.

Comment: @sg552 Thanks for clarifying that, see if my answer below helps you.

Comment: `00-19-D7-53-2D-14` cannot be an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I post the function code.

Comment: @sg552 I finally got your question. I will post a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: @sg552 Has your question been resolved? If so, could you please upvote and accept answers? :)

Comment: not yet. I try to solve it last time but failed. Now I try to find times to solve  this problem. I found a similar question here but I don't have the time...

Answer (score 1):

If the data type for returning mac address is `unsigned char`, you can store that in it.

```
unsigned char output = GetMACaddress() ;
```

If its a sting of characters, use `std::string` to store the mac address returned, if as you say something of the output of the pattern `00-19-D7-53-2D-14`.

```
std::string output = GetMACaddress() ;
```

If it is some other type, you can let the compiler decide that at runtime. If you are using C++11, you can use `auto` or `decltype`.

```
auto return_val = GetMACaddress() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the `stdout` buffer to a stringstream, as below:

```
stringstream ss;
streambuf* old = std::cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf()); // redirect stdout, and also save the old one

GetMACAddress();

string theStr = ss.str();
cout << theStr << endl;

// when you are done, redirect back to the "real" stdout
cout.rdbuf(old);
```

Comment: Thank you but `GetMACAddress();` is not assigned to any variable? `cout << theStr << endl;
cout << theStr << endl;
cout << theStr << endl;` These are suppose to print MAC address 3 time but didn't work?

Comment: No. That would assign the _return value_ of `GetMACAddress()` to that variable. What you want is the string that it prints to the console. The code I pasted above redirects the console (or more precisely, the standard output - known as `stdout`) to the `stringstream`. From there, you get string using `str()` method.

I recommend you read about standard input/output and stringstream to understand how this works.

Comment: FWIW, here's an example code which includes a stripped down version of your code to help you understand. http://ideone.com/W5xnyV I will leave it to you to figure out what's happening.

Comment: I still don't get it. I was hoping I could just `cout << theStr;` and the MAC address will be printed. Can you explain what you mean by this `What you want is the string that it prints to the console.` Do you mean this `theStr`.

Comment: If you do not redirect the stdout stream, `GetMACAddress()` would have printed `00-19-D7-53-2D-14` to the console, right? _That_ is the string I was referring to in my comment. Like I said before, please read about `stdout` to understand what's happening. This might get you started: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdout/

Answer (score 0):

Your function `PrintMACaddress` prints the MAC address; you need a similar function that receives `unsigned char MACData[]` but returns a MAC address instead of printing it.

```
// Converts the MAC address stored in a 6 byte array to a string
std::string ConvertMACaddressToString(unsigned char MACData[])
{
    ...
}
```

To implement it, first replace `printf` by `sprintf`:

```
char result[18]; // 18 bytes are just enough to hold the MAC address
sprintf(result, "%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X", 
    MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
```

Then return the value from the function:

```
return result;
```